# JetBrains IDE embedded terminal cursor disappears while using arrow keys (<- and ->)

Tags: terminal, webstorm, syntax-highlighting, jetbrains-ide, prezto

I'm using zsh/prezto with `syntax-highlighting` plugin. When I use the arrow keys to navigate within the terminal command, the cursor disappears in the embedded terminal and blinks/flashes every ~second.

Here is an example (gif):

[image: enter cursor disappears]

It does not happen within Terminal.app or iterm. If I disable `syntax-highlighting` within `.zpreztorc` it works like expected. =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disabled the cursor highlighter and now it works!

`.zpreztorc`

```
zstyle ':prezto:module:syntax-highlighting' highlighters \
   'main' \
   'brackets' \
   'pattern' \
   'line' \
   'cursor' \ <-- removed
   'root'
```

Comment: Holy f*ck, this was annoying me for months, if not years, and I did not find out the reason...  Feels like a huge burden is gone now...